# how to display icon and text in the toolbar

Tags: android-toolbar, optionmenu

I am working on the following screen:

[image: Screenshot]

On the Toolbar you can see a single tick.I want to display text "Create" along with this also.I am using the following code:

**menu_new_group**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/createGroup"
        android:icon="@drawable/single_tick"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        android:title="Create"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

**Code using option menu**

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear();
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_new_group, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.createGroup:
                createNewGroup();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to add both text and icon as actions in the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

> FYI, It is not possible to show Icon as well as Text of an Action Menu
>   simultaneously in a small spaced Action bar. So we need to make use of
>   `actionLayout` feature to display icon + text.

Check the below sample code for implementation.

**Menu XML**

```
<menu
   xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item
     android:id = "@+id/menu_profile"
     android:icon = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
     android:title = "Save"
     app:actionLayout = "@layout/action_menu"
     app:showAsAction = "always"/>
</menu>
```

**Action Layout - like a normal Layout file with only Textview. action_menu.xml**

```
<TextView
   xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
   android:background = "@drawable/tab_selector"
   android:drawableRight = "@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
   android:gravity = "center"
   android:text = "Save"
   android:textColor = "@android:color/white"/>
```

**Background Selector - for highlighting when clicked. tab_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
     android:drawable = "#eeeeee"
     android:state_pressed = "true"/>
  <item
     android:drawable = "@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

In Code, set click listener as below in onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_profile);
item.getActionView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Save Clicked..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

Best Wishes..

Comment: Glad.. I helped.. NJOY